# Showing image on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Wondering how I would set the set the visibility of the pictures by clicking the button.

```
<body class="body page-index clearfix">
<img class="image image-1" src="http://exmoorpet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat.png">
<img class="image image-2" src="http://exmoorpet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat.png">
<button class="_button" >Test</button>
<img class="image image-3" src="http://exmoorpet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat.png">
```

```
.image {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cz5yyu83/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly include the jQuery library in your head tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And after that use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('._button').click(function(){
        $('.image').css('visibility', 'visible');
    });
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cz5yyu83/1/

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('._button').click(function() {
       $('.image').css('visibility','visible'); 
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hyh9zajp/

With pure Javascript, it is very simple, too:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('_button');
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('image');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    images.style.visibility = "visible";
});
```